# How do I standardize the spacing between items in nested lists in Divi (HTML/CSS)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divi

I'm very new to HTML and this may be an easy fix. I'm updating a Wordpress site using Divi and am creating some nested unordered lists `<ul>` for bullet points with subpoints.

Every subpoint requires an embedded sub-list, and the default formatting seems to mean that the more sub-points, the more space after the parent point.
I screenshot and labeled it to show the variety of spacing:

[image: I screenshot and labeled it to show the variety of spacing.]

I just want the spacing between every list item to be the same, regardless of whether the item has an embedded sub-list.

The code looks pretty normal, I think:

```css
.bullet_list_spacing ul>li {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.bullet_list_spacing ul>li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.bullet_list_spacing ul>li:first-child {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.bullet_list_spacing ul {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet_list_spacing">
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>text
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I tried to remedy the issue by creating and formatting a CSS class (using code from [here](https://divibooster.com/increase-divi-text-module-bullet-list-spacing-and-indent/) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-margins-first-element/)) and then just throwing every variation I could think of at it.

I put the CSS in the "custom CSS" section of Divi's "Appearance" menu ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWtse.png)) and applied the CSS class in the "advanced" section of the text module's settings ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPvB.png)).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the `>` which onyl selects direct childs. Just apply the `margin-top/bottom: 0;` to all `li`. Then you apply `margin-bottom: 16px` to all 2nd level li by using `ul>li>ul>li`. To use the exception of the `last-child` where you dont want this to applied, you can sue the `:not()` selector:

```css
.bullet_list_spacing li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.bullet_list_spacing ul>li>ul>li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullet_list_spacing">
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>text
      <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks helpful, but still had no effect! I realized since none of the code seems to be affecting the text at all, there might be a problem with how I'm doing it in Divi - I'm putting this in "Custom CSS" for the site, and then applying the CSS class to the text module with the list in it - does that seem right?

Comment: Seems about right, have you a link to check?

Comment: The site is confidential until Wednesday, unfortunately, but I've linked screenshots above!